# I can't rerender component to disable btn in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a btn that depends of errors obj,
if there are errors in obj btn will be disabled
disabled={Object.keys(errors).length > 0 ? true : false}
I'm adding the error in another component, but I don't see the rerender in this component
I exactly know that error added in errors, but button not disabled

I have a form in the form I have a Navigation component

```
  <Navigation
    toolName={toolName}
    setDropzoneError={setDropzoneError}
    isSubmit={isSubmit}
    errors={errors}
  />
```

in this component there is a btn that should looks like disabled or nor dependes of amoun errors
here this depending
disabled={Object.keys(errors).length > 0 ? true : false}

also I have a component in this form

```
    <DescriptionAndFiles
      toolName={toolName}
      onFilesSubmit={onFilesSubmit}
      register={register}
      errors={errors}
      dropzoneError={dropzoneError}
      parentTask={parentTask}
      downloadFiles={downloadFiles}
      handleSpChange={handleSpChange}
      setDropError={setDropError}
    />
```

in DescriptionAndFile I have component

```
      <CustomDropzone
        toolName={toolName}
        handleFile={onFilesSubmit}
        dropzoneError={dropzoneError}
        prefetchedFiles={addedPrefetch}
        setDropError={setDropError}
      />
```

if I dropzone is require, but there is not file in drop zone
I print "mistake" and turn dropError to true

```
  if (filesInfo.filesOption === FilesOption.Required) {
    if (constFileList.length === 0 && dropzoneError) {
      dropzoneStyle = `${styles.dropzoneDefault} ${styles.dropzoneNoFiles}`;
      console.log('mistake')
    
      setDropError(true)
      requiredFieldMessage = (
        <p className={errorStyles.errorText}>{intl.get('REQUIRED_FIELD')}</p>
      );
    } else {
      console.log('no mistake')
      setDropError(false)
      dropzoneStyle = styles.dropzoneDefault;
    }
  }
```

so, when I add file I see in console message 'no mistake', when I delete the file from dropzone I see message 'mistake', but button don't change

Comment: Hi, could you post some code please?

Comment: Stackoverflow users do not generally have a Crystal Ball at their disposal, so you will have to give a little bit more details and possibly code if you want to receive any help.